# Permission denied error when using UseUrls() when trying to launch Kestrel

Tags: macos, kestrel, asp.net-core-2.1

I'm trying to run an asp.net core 2.1 app on my mac and am getting the error "Permission Denied" and Kestrel fails to start when I specify the UseUrls() option.

This is my program.cs

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BuildWebHost(args).Run();
    }

    public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseUrls("http://api.dev.mysite.com")
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .UseIISIntegration()
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();
}
```

If I comment out 'UseUrls' then the site launches ok on https://localhost:5001

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kestrel doesn't bind to specific hostnames. `UseUrls()` lets you bind only to the network interface, for example:

```
http://localhost:5000
http://127.0.0.1:5001
http://*:5002
```

If you'd like to use hostname for access, you need to modify **/etc/hosts** file to map the hostname to a localhost, but you'll need to specify the port `http://api.dev.mysite.com:5001` unless it's set to listen on 80 or 443 (for https). Or use reverse proxy like IIS/Nginx/Apache. For Nginx the configuration is:

```
server {
  listen       80;
  server_name  api.dev.mysite.com;
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5001;
  }
}
```